# Change post-self-insert-hook only in one mode

Tags: hooks

I have written a functionality that inserts the word **end** at end of blocks in a lua major mode. How i do it is to check if a space character has been typed, if yes is the word before the space for example `function`, if yes print the **end**. Now adding my funcionality to `post-self-insert-hook` will change its hooks-list in all modes and buffers. How can i specify it to happen only in lua-mode?

Here is my code in my init.el:

```
(add-hook 'lua-mode-hook 'mein-lua-mode-hook)
(defun put-end ()
  "print end of blocks"
  (interactive)
  (backward-char)
  (when (member (thing-at-point 'word) '("function"))
    (progn
      (save-excursion (insert "  " "end"))
      (forward-char))))
(defun spacep ()
  (if (and (derived-mode-p 'lua-mode)(member (char-before) '(13 32)))
      (put-end)))
(defun mein-lua-mode-hook ()
  "Tastaturanbindungen fuer das Lua-Mode"
  ;;; some other things come here
  (add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook 'spacep))
```

Comment: You can use `add-function`, it provides a way to affect buffer locally. Check out its docstring with `[C-h f add-function]`. This could be an option.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `local` argument to `add-hook` is for.
I.e. use

```
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'spacep nil 'local)
```

Answer (score 0):

To have it affect only one mode, have the function test the current mode and do nothing if it is not `(derived-mode-p THE-MODE)`.  In your case, e.g.:

```
(defun spacep ()
  (when (and (derived-mode-p 'lua-mode)
             (member (char-before) '(13 32)))
    (put-end)))
```

Comment: great! Now i am wondering why it only reacts on space (char-code 32) but not with return (13). Do you have any idea?

Comment: Put your cursor after the character that you think is `^M` (13) and hit `C-u C-x =`. I think you'll see that it's not 13. It's likely a newline char (10, not 13).